# Show $\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y) - \sin(x+y)\sin(x-y) = \cos^2x - \sin^2x$

Tags: trigonometry

> Show $\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y) - \sin(x+y)\sin(x-y) = \cos^2x - \sin^2x$

I have got as far as showing that:

$\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y) = \cos^2x\cos^2y -\sin^2x\sin^2y$

and

$\sin(x+y)\sin(x-y) = \sin^2x\cos^2y - \cos^2x\sin^2y$

I get stuck at showing:

$\cos^2x\cos^2y -\sin^2x\sin^2y - \sin^2x\cos^2y - \cos^2x\sin^2y = \cos^2x - \sin^2x$

I know that $\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1$ and I have tried rearranging this identity in various ways, but this has not helped me so far.

Comment: I believe one of your minus signs where you are stuck is incorrect.

Comment: Specifically, the minus sign before $\cos^2x\sin^2y$ should be a plus.

Comment: Hint: $\sin^2 x\sin^2 y + \sin^2 x\cos^2 y = \sin^2 x(\sin^2 y + \cos^2 y) = \sin^2 x$. And yes, as pointed out by JB King, you've got one sign wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at
$\cos^2x\cos^2y -\sin^2x\sin^2y - \sin^2x\cos^2y + \cos^2x\sin^2y$  (The last is a negative times a negative that forms a positive I believe.

You could pull $\sin^2x$ from the middle two terms to get this expression:
$ -\sin^2x\sin^2y - \sin^2x\cos^2y
  = -\sin^2x(\sin^2y+\cos^2y) = -\sin^2x $

There is a similar reduction with the first and last terms around $\cos^2x$ that should make this appear easier.

Comment: The correction of my wrong minus sign was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint**:     $$\cos(a+b)=\cos a \cos b-\sin a \sin b$$$$\cos(2a)=\cos^2 a -\sin ^2a $$

> $$\begin{align}\cos(x+y)\cos(x-y) - \sin(x+y)\sin(x-y) &= \cos((x+y)+(x-y))\\&=\cos2x\\&=\cos^2x - \sin^2x\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice +1 ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: @Peter Tamaroff:thanks peter

Comment: It’s really a matter of pattern recognition rather than of mathematics.

Comment: @Lubin How is "pattern recognition" dissociated from "mathematics"?

Comment: Although I upvoted your comment, @PeterTamaroff, there are many cases of pattern recognition that have nothing to do with mathematics, unless one force an unnaturally broad definition on mathematics; and there are many mathematical ideas and techniques that have nothing to do with pattern recognition.